# No CSS on any *.stackexchange.com sites, except meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[image]

So that's programmers.

Chat is broken the same way.

Comment: Humm... no repo for me (UK) (cdn.sstatic.net resolves to 198.252.206.16 for me).

Comment: I'm not sure why, but the hostname lookup keeps sending me to the US side instead of Europe. I'm not sure how they handle geo distribution at cloudflare, but something seems wonky to me.

Comment: In UK and can reproduce.

Comment: It appears to be the cdn.sstatic.net that is having issues, not SE itself.

Comment: The CDN is down... and now it's back (8:39 PDT).

Comment: CloudFlare's latest tweet says that they are investigating upstream issues in North America, as of 8 mins ago... (https://twitter.com/CloudFlareSys).

Comment: They pointed the CDN back to their own servers instead of cloudflare.

Comment: We're on this now (and have been aware of it, sorry for the delay in commenting).

Comment: @TimPost it's all good! #DevOops is hard, man. :-)

Comment: @Tim so, who's at fault this time? :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard yours. :P

Comment: @Sha [I don't know...](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DMXjY.png)

Comment: */me crawls back silently to the darknet, feeling sorry I asked @Tim* :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We were having Cloudflare CDN issues, but [they've been resolved](https://stackstatus.tumblr.com/post/98978864789/were-back).

You can always check [@StackStatus on Twitter](https://twitter.com/StackStatus) or the [StackStatus blog](https://www.stackstatus.net/) for information during these types of problems.

Comment: Maybe you would want to add that cloudflare actually messed up and you reverted to a backup solution. Not that it matters to most, but for someone who believes that a CDN solution gives you 100% availability, this might be an eye opener :) https://blog.cloudflare.com/route-leak-incident-on-october-2-2014/